# On basic idea of a random variable.

Tags: probability-theory

Should one think of a random variable as a function, whos range happen to be subject to randomness? Or does something get lost thinking like this?

Could has been changed to should.

Comment: A random variable is a measure function that maps the outcome of a random process to some evaluation.  So, basically, yes.

Comment: Did you at least search for the definition of a random variable? It is precisely a function from probability space to, say, $\mathbb{R}$ or any other measurable space.

Comment: @GrahamKemp "measure function" > "measurable function".

Comment: Ah, indeed. @Did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO you should exactly *not* think of a random variable as function, but as quantity whose value you are not sure about, which is why you describe this quantity via probability densities, expectation, etc.

This is despite the fact that formally random variables are of course defined as functions from a probability space to the real numbers, which is an admittedly ingenious construction. However, most often you are not interested in the probability space by itself, neither in the exact function, but really just in derived intuitive properties of the function viewed as random variable, like its expectation (this has an intuitive meaning independent of the underlying probability space. Only the formalization goes via integral of a function on the probability space), higher moments, and most importantly the probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ itself. In practice, sets of random variables are often equivalent when all these properties are the same, i.e., it is irrelevant with which probability spaces and functions thereon they are defined.

Comment: "you should exactly not think of a random variable as function" Huh? To neglect the exact probability space these are defined upon and to concentrate on the image measures (aka distributions) is definitely the way to go... but this does not mean what you say in the quote.

Comment: This is the dilemma im stuck with...nice formulation, I see Did point tho. This is very hard to formulate good.

Comment: @Did I do maintain what I said in that quote. I don't think of a random variable as a function. I work with it as a function, when I do math. But my intuition about random variables does not come from thinking about functions sending little omegas to real numbers. When two random variables are independent, I don't think "aha, so the probability measure factors over preimages under those random variables", but as   "aha, decreasing my uncertainty about the one quantity does not affect anything I know about the other one". Maybe you have another interpretation about whay I say in the quote?

Comment: The OP asked "Could one think of a RV as a function whose range ..." and I wanted to make a point against THINKING of a random variable as a function as an intuitive way to go. To be honest, I didn't exactly understand what was meant with the ellipsis-part, and what other way of thinking the function-thinking was compared to

Comment: @Bananach https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2396508/on-basic-idea-of-random-variable-2