# On basic idea of random variable 2

Tags: probability-theory, soft-question, intuition

A while ago I asked the following question, [On basic idea of a random variable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705555/on-basic-idea-of-a-random-variable)

Looking into probability theory again after some time made me think of the following analogy.

Consider the idea of an operator on a vector space, it has a matrix given some basis and without a basis the operator is rather abstract.

Is the situation the same with "random quantities"? I.e it is not a function unless you have a given probability space? without it it is just its distrubution in some sense.

Comment: A random variable is, by definition, a function with a measurability condition. Changing the sigma-algebra on the source space Omega may imply that some given function X is not measurable anymore, yes, hence that it is not a random variable anymore. Is this your question?

Comment: ((No idea what (intuition) might refer to, here.))

Comment: @Did there are many pespectives of a random variables, understanding more of them and thier consequences increases one's "intuition".

Comment: @Did Do you understand my example with the operator? And am I right that the same "random variables" might be modeled by two diffrent measureable funtions on two different prob. spaces?

Comment: @Did take $\Omega_{1}=\{1,2\}$ and $\Omega_{2}=\{3,4\}$ then let $X$ and $Y$ be defined on these respectively take same values $a$ and $b$ with some probabilites. $X$ and $Y$ is not the same, but from a probabilistc point of view one could arguee that they are.

Comment: "Do you understand my example with the operator?" Yes, and the comparison with linear maps is flawed because the same linear map is never simultaneously linear with respect to some given basis and not linear with respect to another basis while the same function may be measurable with respect to some given pair of sigma-algebras and not measurable with respect to some other pair.

Comment: "And am I right that the same "random variables" might be modeled by two diffrent measureable funtions on two different prob. spaces?" Hmmm, this is taking your question to another setting. Now it seems you are confusing **random variables** (that are merely functions defined on some given space with values in another given space) with their **distributions** (that are measures on the sigma-algebra of the target space of the function). Yes, a given distribution corresponds to several different functions, possibly defined on different source spaces.

Comment: @Did my point being is that a random variables essentially is its  values and thier respective probabilies.

Comment: "my point being is that a random variables essentially is its values and thier respective probabilies" And this is where you are wrong. See my previous comment.

Comment: @Did I think I see your point now. I think I really wanna say distribution and not random variable. What about think of the analogy between a distribution and an operator in the same vein?

Comment: What would be the analogue of changing the vector basis basis used to express a linear map, for a distribution?

Comment: @Did well not in that sense, just in the sense of being an abstarct idea which often gets mixed up with the contrete one, such as the matrix of and operator being the operator and the random varibles being the distrituion. When it really a mather of modeling with somthing with abstract stuctures.

Comment: Most linear maps have several matrix representations (obtained by changing the basis of the source and target vector spaces defining the map). Any distribution can be realized by several random variables (obtained by changing the probability space and even, most often, the function defined on it). If this is the analogy you have in mind, then it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from @Did's comment above:

> Most linear maps have several matrix representations (obtained by changing the basis of the source and target vector spaces defining the map). Any distribution can be realized by several random variables (obtained by changing the probability space and even, most often, the function defined on it). If this is the analogy you have in mind, then it is correct.